# Use personal method in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know if it's possible to use a method that I have created into a LINQ ?

```
var usr = db.Utilisateurs.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == user.Login &&  CreateASCIIMD5Hash(u.password) == user.password);
```

but i'm having an error :

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `System.String CreateASCIIMD5Hash(System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You mean you created `CreateASCIIMD5Hash` yourself and you want to use it in a Linq expression?

Comment: you can use it in LINQ but not LINQ to entities

Comment: How would that private method translate to SQL? You can't use anything in L2E that doesn't translate to SQL and that's A Good Thing. LINQ to SQL allowed you to use your own methods by loading loading the results into memory, then converting the oparation to LINQ to Objects. You could load an entire table into memory without warning

Comment: @Glubus Yes i'm trying to hash the password from the controller

Comment: @Kamil there's no reason at all to do that in the query. Hash the password *before* the query

Comment: @Kamil: No you're not, you're trying to hash the password that's in the database.  Shouldn't that *already* be hashed?

Comment: @Kamil: an MD5 hash is no hash. It's trivial to break. Why are you creating your *own* authentication? ASP.NET and .NET in general already provides secure mechanisms that properly hash and salt passwords, and use *secure* algorithms like SHA256 (at least). Password hashing also requires at least 1000 iterations to ensure the password isn't easy to crack

Comment: @Kamil far worse, the signature implies there is no salt. A rainbow table, ie a table with passwords and precalculated hashes could be used to find the password *faster* than your code can hash and compare the values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos MD5 is definietly a hash, it might not be secure, but that is not within the definition of what a hash is.

Comment: @Glubus when talking about passwords MD5 isn't a hash. It's a party invitation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos MD5 is a hashing technique regardless of the context it is used in. You saying that you should not use it as a hashing function for hashing passwords is correct on merit of the fact that MD5 is not a safe hashing function for it. You saying that MD5 is not a hashing function is incorrect, and creates a confusing environment for people that don't know what a hashing function is to begin with.

Comment: @Glubus it's precisely these people that should understand that they should never, ever use it for passwords. I think it's crystal clear what I meant and that I never used the phrase `MD5 is not a hash`.

Comment: I will second everyone telling you to USE BUILTINs to do crypto unless you actually know what you are doing or you basically have no security

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's my point, it's **not** crystal clear that it is not a hash. People googling on this subject trying to learn something about hashing might interpret your ambiguous statement the wrong way and will end up confused. SO is a place for learning, the fact that you're very opinionated on the subject does not allow you to start throwing around statements that are vague, even if it is irrelevant to the point you are  trying to make. When I corrected  you, you even said "MD5 isn't a hash. It's a party invitation", which is just malicious and has no place on this forum.

Comment: @Glubus I disagree. It's not malicious, nor opinionated. It's a comment. You can flag it if you want. You can take it up at `meta`. Others seem to agree with me

Comment: @Glubus He did say that in terms of passwords that it's not a hash which I completely agree with.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. A comment is still a comment regardless if it is malicious or not. My point is that you're saying things that aren't factual on a forum where people expect things to be factual. I agree with you that MD5 should not be used for hashing passwords, and I agree with you that using a salt is essential. I'm just trying to convince  you of not using statements as "MD5 isn't a hash. It's a party invitation" on a forum where people come to learn from people more experienced (like yourself). They will take it literally and it will slow down their development.

Comment: @DavidG Then how would you describe MD5 'in the context of passwords'? I don't think MD5 is defined in that manner.

Comment: @Glubus About as useful as doing ROT13 encryption

Comment: @DavidG That's how you would describe MD5? If someone asked you what MD5 is, you'd say: "About as useful as doing ROT13 encryption". Again, I'm not stating that MD5 is a **valid** function for hashing passwords. However, it remains **defined** as a hashing function, regardless of the context it is used in. It could be a very very very bad hashing function, still it remains what it is.

Comment: @Glubus You asked for a description "in the context of passwords" and I gave you my answer. I'm not going to get into further religious discussion here any more. You made your point and I have made mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch your query round, hash the input password before sending it to the database:

```
var hash = CreateASCIIMD5Hash(user.password);

var usr = db.Utilisateurs
    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == user.Login && 
                         u.password == hash);
```

Side note: The name of your hash function implies you're using a terrible and insecure hashing method...

Comment: And no salt - one wouldn't even have to work to crack this. A simple rainbow table would retrieve the password immediatelly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh, rainbow table, not heard that term before, nice.

Comment: @DavidG It's a pretty obsolete approach at this point.  Cracking the password from scratch is going to be seconds up to most common password lengths, so there's no need to optimize it the way there was back when it would take hours/years.  These days a rainbow table is likely to be *slower* given the amount of Disk IO required.

Comment: It's working just fine. Thank you for your help. I'm going to try changing the hash method.

Comment: @Kamil don't try to change the hash method. Remove it entirely and use the built-in mechanisms. Try to implement your own only *after* you understand how password hashing works. Check Troy Hunt's [Stronger password hashing in .NET with Microsoft’s universal providers](https://www.troyhunt.com/stronger-password-hashing-in-net-with/)

Comment: @Kamil Or just read anything by Troy Hunt and you'll end up so terrified about your security that you'll be uber careful in future :)

Comment: Ok, I have been searching how to hash a string but not enough according to your sayings.